# Error al reconocer campo del modelo de datos con ADO.NET y ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, razor, ado.net

Estoy usando Web APIS pero solo en el Controlador. En mi vista no puedo acceder al modelo me dice que falta un using o algo así. Lo que yo quiero es generar un input type de tipo texto para que capture el valor y filtrar por nombre de clientes.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: probablemente en tb_clientes no tengas definido a NombreCIa o este no se encuentre público.

Answer (score 0):

Html Helpers no funcionan con colecciones pero tienes `@model IEnumerable<apiuno.Models.tbl_clientes>`, que es una coleccion, definido como tu modelo.

Intenta cambiandolo a:

`@model apiuno.Models.tbl_clientes`

O definiendolo en html:

```
<input type="text" name="NombreCia" />
```